# How to update datasource of handle bad layer with Python console in QGIS 3.4

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-3, qgis-python-console, data-source

How do I update the datasource of file project in QGIS, for example myexample.qgz from Python console?

What is the command needed, or scripts standalone?

For example:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer() 
newDatasource = "/home/usuario/EJES2020.shp" 
newProvider = "ogr"
?.setDataSource('EJES2018',newProvider, newDatasource, extent)
```